# Get-Content Replace a full string

Tags: powershell

So I have the following command:

```
(Get-Content $path).Replace($current, $new) | Set-Content $path
```

It works fine for changing a string but lets say I have the following string in `$path` : `"This is a test. testing was done."`

If i set `$current` to `"test"` and `$new` to `"Blah"`. I'll get `"This is a Blah. Blahing was done."`

How do I make it so that it only changes `"test"` and not `"testing"` so my string would be: `"This is a blah. testing was done."`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $path = "This is a test. testing was done."   
 $current = "\btest\b" 
 $new = "Blah"
 $path -replace ($current, $new)
```

\b is a regular expression word boundary

Comment: Lets say $current is passed to the script.  How can i add the "\b" to the start and end of it?  I tried adding it with "+" and some other variations but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I don't quite understand - can you show me the code?

Comment: param (
    [string]$path = "",
    [string]$new = "",
    [string]$current = "")
(Get-Content $path).Replace($current, $new) | Set-Content $path

Comment: The \b is a regular expression word boundary, which is why I changed your code from using the Replace() method to the -replace operator, as the -replace operator recognises regular expressions.  In your code you have gone back to using the replace method so the \b will not work

Comment: That was my bad, i had just copied and pasted my code above. Lets say i do use the code you provided.  How would i add \b to the start of $current?

Comment: Exactly as I have done set it as the variable    `$current = "\bWord_to be_matched\b"`

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `Replace()` method, try using the `-replace` operator - this operator uses regular expressions as described in [Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) (link is to MSDN).

Comment: Got distracted and called away to something else - I was actually thinking that `\W` might have been appropriate for the OP's needs. I'm also a little shaky on regexp analysis, so would have been hesitant to mention any specific pattern.